# Extremum problem with multiple unknown variables

Tags: calculus, optimization

(This is a homework question): 
We move with constant speed from A to B with $v_1$ and from B to C with $v_2$.

($v_1 < v_2$) and ($x <= b$) is known.

[Please have a look at the image for clarity. Description of the image:  We move (From a bird's eye view) diagonally from A to B and in a straight line from B to C.$$\begin{align*}
A(0|a)         \\
B(x|0)   \\
C(b|0)\end{align*}$$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LvQk.jpg)

How do we choose x in dependence of $a, v_1,v_2$, so that we minimize the total amount of time needed to get to C?

What I have tried far:

$$t=\dfrac{s_{1}}{v_{1}}+\dfrac{s_{2}}{v_{2}}$$

$$s_{1}=\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}$$

$$s_{2}=b-x$$

$$t=\dfrac{\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}{v_{1}}+\dfrac{b-x}{v_{2}}$$

And I am stuck. I *think* calculating the derivative and solving it for $0$ is not feasible right now and that maybe there is some way to get rid of more variables.

How do I need to proceed?

Thank You

Comment: it is feasible to solve if you use $$ \frac {x}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2} }=\frac {1}{\sqrt{ 1+(\frac{a}{x})^2} }$$

Comment: Okay, so this is  $$sin\alpha=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+cot^{2}\alpha}}$$, I do not understand how to apply this formula, as I understand it if I try to solve this for a or x I end up with 1=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$t=\dfrac{\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}{v_{1}}+\dfrac{b-x}{v_{2}}$$
$$\implies \frac{dt}{dx} = \frac 1{v_1}\frac x{  \sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}} -\frac 1{v_2}$$
for min , must have $ \frac{dt}{dx} = 0$
$$\implies  \frac 1{v_1}\frac x{  \sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}} =\frac 1{v_2}$$

now use my hint ( which is valid for $x \ge 0$) to solve for $x$ in terms of $a, b, v_1, v_2$.

It happens for this problem that $x$ does not depend on $b$ ( except for the condition $x \le b$ )

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your help. Secondly, I could not figure out how to use the hint but think that it is unnecessary. My assumption that you cannot solve the derivative as is appears to be wrong. I was simply messing up the calculation. The only *real* variable left in the equation is x, the others are simply parameters, so it should be solvable as is. I end up with $$x=\sqrt{\dfrac{(v_{1}/v_{2})^{2}*a^{2}}{1-(v_{1}/v_{2})^{2}}}$$ which according to a simulation I ran in geogebra should be correct.